# Yesterdays Date in XSLT

Tags: xslt, date, xslt-1.0

How can you find yesterday's date in xslt? I was thinking of getting today's date and then subtracting one day, but I don't know how to do that without breaking the calendar.

Comment: What version of xslt are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In `XSLT 2.0` you can use `current-dateTime()` method to get current date. But if you are using `XSLT 1.0` , you need to use an extension function as  XSLT 1.0 does not provide any standard to get the current date/time.
You could use the following script in `XSLT 1.0`

```
<ms:script language="javascript" implements-prefix="user">
    function datediff(date1, date2)
    {
        return Math.round(((new Date(date2)) - (new Date(date1))/1000/60);
    }
</ms:script>
```

Comment: This is assuming we're using MSXML. Saxon has a similar extension, `<saxon:script>`, but I'm not sure if it can handle javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet would be to write an extension in your native programming language, and use your native language's datemath library.  You can read more about the basics of it at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-callbk/index.html

This example uses Java, but I've worked with this a lot in .NET

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [EXSLT](http://exslt.org/date/index.html)'s extension for date functions:

```
date:add(date:date(), '-P1D')
```

`date:date()` retrieves the current date, and `date:add()` adds a duration to it. "-P1D" represents a duration of -1 day.

Note these extension functions are not in the XSLT standard, but implementations can be found, depending on what XSLT processor you're using. EXSLT functions should be a bit more portable than processor-specific ones like `<ms:*>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to get previous date at work with only XSLT 1.0 available to me. As result, I've come up with a transformation, that can do just that. You can check it on Github: https://github.com/Simbiat/xslt1_previous_day

The logic behind it splitting the date into 3 components and operating with them separately, yet maintaining dependency and dealing with zeros.
So, I subtract 1 from day first, then, if I got 0 - subtract it from month, while reverting the day to its maximum value (31). Same is done for month and year, respectively. For days there is additional logic dependent on month (and year for February), since last day of month can be 28, 29, 30 or 31.